# Trimming csv file by removing columns-PYTHON

Tags: python

What is the simplest way to trim a large csv file by removing columns? Also, instead of choosing a range of columns to keep, can I pick and choose what columns to keep?

Comment: `pandas` should be able to do that easily

Comment: Please show what did you try so far.

Comment: does your CSV file have header line (with column names)?

Comment: so the simplest way i know would be: `import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', usecols=['col_to_keep_1', 'col_to_keep_2', ...]).to_csv('output.csv', index=False)`

Comment: You don't need pandas. although it works perfectly well, its not necessarily preinstalled on people's systems. There are plenty of examples of using the `csv` module to read and write files. Post some code and we can go from there.